# Component p:printer without last row

Tags: primefaces, printing-web-page

I have a datatable with celleditor and I want to print a datatable without the last row.

I am allowing to add a new row and when I go to print  I want to remove row blanc.
With the remote command I remove the line, but the line appears on the printout.

bean.java

```
public void addRow(){
   listTest.add(new Teste(0, 0));
   PrimeFaces requestContext = PrimeFaces.current();
   requestContext.executeScript("PF('dtTestesVar').addRow()");
}

public void remove() {
   listTest.remove(listTest.size()-1);
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<p:panel id="printer" style="border: 0px !important;">

<p:dataTable id="dtTestes" var="teste"
value="#{vc.testes}" editable="true"
editMode="cell" widgetVar="dtTestesVar">
(...)
</p:dataTable>

</p:panel>


<p:remoteCommand name="rc"
 update="dtTestes"
 actionListener="#{vc.remove}" />

<p:commandButton type="button" value="Print" onclick="rc()"
icon="ui-icon-print">
<p:printer target="printer" />
</p:commandButton>
```

My Solution:

```
<p:commandButton value="print" actionListener="#{vc.removeRow}" process="@this" update="dt" oncomplete="$('#form\\:print').click(); addRow();" /> 
<p:commandButton id="print" value="myprint" style="visibility: hidden;"> 
<p:printer target="dt" /> 
</p:commandButton> <p:remoteCommand name="addRow" actionListener="#{vc.addRow}" update="dt" />
```

Comment: What is the relation of JDBC with printing? And the java tag should only be used if you have issues with a class with just a main method that can be reproduced with only a jdk and not additional libraries.

Comment: This question is NOT java-se related. Can you download a plain jdk, just put the code in there that is in your question (not using a tomat with jsf etc) and reproduce the problem?  And please check the order in which things are executed. The printing takes place before the remote command has finished, so all seems to work as you tell it to do. So make sure the print executes after the updates

Comment: Any progress to report?

Comment: the print execute after the updates....

Comment: So it works? Why did you not report this back? And earlier? And please create an answer yourself what you actually changed

Comment: code like this in comments is unreadable. Edit the question. and add an 'update'  in there

Comment: Don't work...    Please, check the commandButton and remoteCommand.                                                                                                  _I want to execute the first action to remove() and then <printer>_, the problem is priority is <printer>  and then remove() @Kukeltje

Comment: Yes, I all know this. But that is just what **your** code does... Just do an explicit remove on in an action on the commandButton and AFTER that (oncomplete?) do a print, by e.g. faking a click on a hidden button... Or just hide the last row with CSS, waaaaay more simple.

Comment: can you give an example? @Kukeltje

Comment: Of the css? That should be easy to do yourself...

Comment: And this is? Code like this in comments is not really readable. Update the question (with an explicit part at the end that says 'update: '... and without a textual explanation it is even harder